# Why got invalid socket in eclipse debug mode only?

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

In eclipse C++ I got an invalid socket when starting the debug mode. 
The error is WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT.
I got this error when using the debugger only. Starting with run, the creation of the socket is successful.
Under VisualStudio the same code  runs in debug and release mode.

Debugging with eclipse and mingw works fine when no socket is used.
It seems to be a problem with the configuration of gdb, because eclipse is using the same exe independent if I start with run or with debug (there is no change of the timestamp which I change the configuration).

The configuration is: eclipse 4.6.3, Mingw32-gcc-g++ V6.3.0-1, I linked the libws2_32 from \Mingw\lib, under Windows 10, 64bit.
\Mingw\bin is added to the path variable under Windows and in Eclipse itself.

This is the the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    WORD sockVer = MAKEWORD(2, 0);
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET listener;
    SOCKADDR_IN servInfo;

    servInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servInfo.sin_port = htons(80);

    WSAStartup(sockVer, &wsaData);

    listener = socket(servInfo.sin_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (listener == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        int lastErr = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << "Error = " << lastErr << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Listener = " << listener << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what [`WSAStartup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) returns?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not trying to debug in eclipse when it's already running in the background?

Comment: Why are you asking for Winsock 1.1?  Try asking for Winsock 2.0.

Comment: WSAStartup returns 0.

Comment: using Winsock 2.0 has the same behaviour, 2.2 as well

Comment: "... already running in the background" -> In the debug window I see one application with 4 threads.

Comment: In the mean time, I tried it on Win7 with the same eclipse and mingw version. There it runs fine. It seems it is a problem on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I found it by myself. I removed the workspace and created a new one. With the new one it runs. I don't know what happend.